# Error generating QR code in ASP.net + Report viewer with QrCoder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, qr-code, rdlc, reportviewer

I am trying to generate a report with Qr codes I am using this video as a guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW99WK6SQKI
I did tests before and it worked and then it stopped working and it just shows me that error nothing more.

I am working with ASP.net MVC + Report Viewer

I looked for the error in the forums and I can't find a solution...

```
Error while loading code module: ‘QRCoder, Version=1.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'QRCoder, Version=1.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. C:\DevOps\Project\Report\Qr.rdlc
```

**IDE**
[image]

**IMAGEN PROPERTIES**
[image]

**REPORT PROPERTIES
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Nouman, I did it several times, remove and add again,
also the drawing

Answer (score 0):

`PublicKeyToken` value should not be null. You need to get the `PublicKeyToken` from QrCoder dll and use it.

To find the Public key token.

1. Open visual studio developer command prompt.
2. Run `sn -Tp <AssemblyName>` 

    **e.g. `sn -Tp c:\libraries\QRCoder.dll`**
3. Use Public key value in `PublicKeyToken=<Value>`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, I cleaned the project inside the solution and build it as "Release" (Because the problem appeared in the production environment), found the problem fixed.